# Visual Studio Code, map and scroll bar out of sync

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to make the code map and scroll bar line up? As it is, they both scroll at different speeds, are different sizes, and the highlights on the scroll bar don't like up with the map. I can't find anything in settings or any other info online.

[Image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtUQi.png)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not possible.

[#20934 Render more than characters inside the minimap](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20934)

[#21849 Show Full Document](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21849)

Comment: Thanks Alex. So this is planned? The Visual Studio map is pretty much perfect for me, and this is the only niggle I have with VSCode at the moment.

Comment: I can only say that it's on the roadmap: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Roadmap#editor